# Uneven border width near corners using CSS

Tags: css, css-shapes

I have a border shape for my website's images, that I need to convert to css. Right now, I have the border saved as an image and used the image to make the border around my images. However, I would like to know if it is possible to do the same job, but with plain CSS.

The border shape is the following image:

[image]

As you can see, the border width is not the same all around, as it becomes thicker near the top-left and bottom-right corner (rotated a bit). Is this even possible to do with CSS? I know you can set the width for the different sides, but that would not give the same result as the above image.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This looks like a case for SVG if ever I saw one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a *hacky* way to approximate this using CSS:

```css
.box {
  margin:0 40px;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  border:7px solid;
  border-radius:30px;
  transform:skew(20deg);
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 47%,#000 50%) top/100% 20px,
    linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 47%,#000 50%) right/20px 100%,
    radial-gradient(circle at bottom left, transparent 50%,#000 52%) top right/57px 57px,  
    
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 47%,#000 50%) bottom/100% 20px,
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 47%,#000 50%) left/20px 100%,
    radial-gradient(circle at top right, transparent 50%,#000 52%) bottom left/57px 57px;
    
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Also like this:

```css
.box {
  margin:0 40px;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  border:7px solid;
  border-radius:30px;
  transform:skew(20deg);
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 47%,#000 50%) top/100% 20px,
    radial-gradient(circle at bottom left, transparent 50%,#000 52%) calc(100% + 15px) 0/57px 57px,
    
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 47%,#000 50%) bottom/100% 20px,
    radial-gradient(circle at top right, transparent 50%,#000 52%) -15px 100%/57px 57px;
    
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```