# Uneven Border on Corners

Tags: html, css

How could I create a border somewhere among the lines of this?

[image: Sample]

I've tried using linear gradients for backgrounds (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52701579/uneven-border-width-near-corners-using-css)) but can't seem to get it to draw the shape I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could use before and after pseudo elements on the main element to create a background. One would be a red rectangle, and in front of it a white rectangle with CSS clip-path used to get the shape.

Here's an example. Obviously change the % values to be what you want (could be px if that is required).

```css
body {
  background: black;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

div {
  width: 30vmin;
  height: 50vmin;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

div::before,
div::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

div::before {
  background: red;
}

div::after {
  background: white;
  clip-path: polygon(5% 5%, 50% 0, 95% 5%, 100% 30%, 100% 70%, 95% 95%, 70% 100%, 30% 100%, 5% 95%, 0 70%, 0 30%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a gradient, here is an idea using conic-gradient. All you have to do is adjust a few variables to control the shape

```css
.box {
  --size: 15px;
  --angle: 250deg;
  --g: red var(--angle), lightblue 0; /* the colors here */

  background:
    conic-gradient(from calc(var(--angle)/-2 -  45deg) 
      at top    var(--size) left  var(--size),var(--g)) top left,
    conic-gradient(from calc(var(--angle)/-2 + 45deg) 
      at top    var(--size) right var(--size),var(--g)) top right,
    conic-gradient(from calc(var(--angle)/-2 - 135deg) 
      at bottom var(--size) left  var(--size),var(--g)) bottom left,
    conic-gradient(from calc(var(--angle)/-2 + 135deg) 
      at bottom var(--size) right var(--size),var(--g)) bottom right;
  background-size: 51% 51%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="--size:10px; --angle: 255deg"></div>
```